# Workflow sum 2 field values

Tags: netsuite

I have a 3 fields - all decimal fields:

```
custbody_myvalue1
custbody_myvalue2
custbody_myvalue3
```

I need to have custbody_myvalue3 = the sum of custbody_myvalue1 and custbody_myvalue2 via a workflow.

In my workflow I have a formula that sets the value for custbody_myvalue3 whenever either of the 2 other fields are edited:

```
{custbody_myvalue1}+{custbody_myvalue2}
```

But this is combining the 2 values - not giving me the sum. If I change the formula to multiply the 2 fields the math works.

What is the proper way to do this in a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Apparently you need to parse the values in order to sum them.

See SA93584.

> Javascript in workflow formula considers "+" operation as adding not
> summing and treats a value behind "+" as a string which results in
> adding one number behind another, NaN (Not a Number) error or any
> other error.
>
> Therefore it is needed to command Javascript to treat a value as a
> number. For this purpose can be used only the available functions in
> formula builder or SuiteScript functions such as nlapiGetFieldValue.
>
> For instance for the beforehand mentioned arithmetic operations the
> following syntax has to be used in order the formula to work properly:
>
> parseFloat(nlapiGetFieldValue('field1') || 0) +
> parseFloat(nlapiGetFieldValue('field2') || 0) -
> parseFloat(nlapiGetFieldValue('field3') || 0)